# Order by long Distance from Google Distance Matrix

Tags: c#, linq, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

Google Distance Matrix API for long distance between the origin and destination respond with a blank space when it's > 1000km: "1 865"

When I try to order the result using LINQ:

```
.OrderBy(g => Double.Parse(g.Distance, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-PT")))
```

I get the error:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
```

I tried to remove the blank space using g.Distance.replace(" ","") but it's not working.

Comment: if for any value in the list, you have distance as null, the Parse method will through exception.

Comment: Hi, I have tested and checked and I don't have any value null

Comment: Honestly, I was about to delete my answer without waiting for your reply (what you thought that was my request about? I assumed that you weren't able to do by your own what you were supposed to be doing). Your answer has confirmed my decision. SO is very big, thus I hope that we both will be enjoying it without having to deal with each other again :) PS: I promise you that I thought twice (and thrice) before posting an answer here (I am trying to avoid people like you); not sure why, because you and the question seemed OK, but I felt something weird... I should have trusted my guts.

Answer (score 0):

After debuging the string returned by Google Distance Matrix API, I found that the character is the Chr(160) and to remove it I used the function (directly in the returned value from the API):

```
.Replace(Convert.ToChar(160).ToString(), "");
```

And now I can orderBy without any problem:

```
.OrderBy(g => Double.Parse(g.Distance, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-PT")))
```